# Input group with label and dropdown only (<input hidden>) (avoid <select>)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an input label with drop down only, as I am trying to avoid `select` as per recommendation.

I have the code below, using input-grp however I can't figure out how to not show the `<input type="text">` in between. Is this possible to make this `<input type="hidden">` while maintaining good looks?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Language</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="I want to hide this input text make it type=hidden">
  <div class="input-group-btn open">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" >English (en-US) <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin: 0 auto;">
          <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">French (fr)</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Spanish (es-ES)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You dont need the text box above french? is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Sreekanth I need to make the textbox with placeholder "Search" be invisible.

Comment: What about making it transparent

Comment: Thanks @JonesJoseph - my issue is that gap that is in between "Language" and the "Action" menu button, I want to close that gap up too.

Comment: Do you need that textbox to placed there? hide it or remove it completely?

Comment: @JonesJoseph I am trying to remove it or making `type=hidden` which ever works. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to override the styles inherited by the elements.

Visibility hidden makes sure that you have your original layout intact, just that the elements are not hidden.

This is what you could do.

```css
/* override Styles here. */
.custom .input-group-addon + input {
  display: none;
}
.custom .dropdown-menu-right{
  right:auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group custom"> <span class="input-group-addon">Language</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="I want to hide this input text make it type=hidden">
  <div class="input-group-btn open">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">English (en-US) <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin: 0 auto;">
          <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">French (fr)</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Spanish (es-ES)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Sreekanth for this, however the issue I'm having is that gap in between the "English (en-us)" and the "Language" fields, I was hoping to close that up, is this possible? I up voted though for your great efort to help me!

Comment: You could change it to behave as you want, using display none and overrride another css. Not sure, if thats what you need.

Comment: yes please that's what I am struggling with. edit: oh wow I saw you did it! thank you so much!!